# Struggling in saving all values present in my Listview in SharedPreference

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Facing issue while saving all values from Custom ListView in SharedPreference.

Actually, My Layout contains one checkbox,textview(Custom Listview) and one more checkbox(select_all) for selecting all data present in my Custom Listview.
While clicking on select_all checkbox, all values present in Custom Listview got selected but only top 13 values got stored in my SharedPreference.
Here is my Program snippet,

```
        selectAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean isChecked = selectAll.isChecked();

            if (isChecked) {


                for (int i = 0; i < exportItems.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    listViewLayout = (LinearLayout) exportItems
                            .getChildAt(i);
                    cb = (CheckBox) listViewLayout
                            .findViewById(R.id.export_chk);

                    if (strTypes.equals("Orders/Invoices")) {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        ordRefNo = ordersList.get(i)
                                .getHhTran_referenceNumber();
                        supporter.saveOrderInPreference(ordRefNo, 1);

                    } else if (strTypes.equals("Credit Note")) {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        cnRefNo = creditNoteList.get(i)
                                .getHhTran_referenceNumber();
                        supporter.saveCreditNoteInPreference(cnRefNo, 1);
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        docNo = receiptList.get(i).getHhReceipt_docnumber();
                        supporter.saveReceiptInPreference(docNo, 1);
                    }

                }

                orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                creditNoteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                receiptAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {

                unCheckAll();
            }
        }
    });
```

So,Can Anyone helped me out in storing all values present in my Listvew into
SharedPreference.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's better to saved all the values in `SQLite` with name and Ids. It's very easy and fast to handle.

Comment: Even though i will try to save it in SQLite the value is not coming...As i told only top 13 values from my Listview is coming since i'm using exportItems.getChildCount() but nearly 40 values were present in my ListView(all Checked) @MD

Comment: share your ListView's adapter code, so that i can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is not suitable for receiving input from user. Because you have to save all views with input. If you not do this, after scroll everything will cleared. I think ScrollView is better for this situation.

Anyway if you want to use ListView, you can't trust views. So, after every action you have to fill your data(using from ListView) and call notifyDataSetChanged() to ListView refresh itself.

PS 1: You should think that ListView only shows my views, it must not manipulate them. It's the point.

PS 2: Use listener and TextWatcher for capturing inputs and saving at your data.

PS 3: I used Listview with EditTexts and I warn you, it is pain in the ass :)